# How Do I Integrate a Datepicker On a Custom Field Within a Channel Form?

Tags: channel-form

I've been searching high and low and have been unable to find a basic guide for including the EE datepicker on a custom field in a Channel Form.

What code do I need to add to the following to add a datepicker to the input field?

```
    {exp:channel:form channel="event_public" return="/" datepicker="yes" }
...
      <label for="event_date">Date*</label><br />
      <input type="text" name="event_date" id="event_date" value="{event_date}" maxlength="23" size="25"><br />
...
    {/exp:channel:form}
```

Thanks!

Randy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you need to add the `datepicker` class to the input. By default, that's the selector that is used for instantiate the jQuery datepicker widget.

Comment: Thanks! I think that was what I needed, but it's still not working—I'm getting a JS error within the datepicker code that's automatically added. It's on this line:

`$.datepicker.setDefaults({dateFormat:$.datepicker.W3C+EE.date_obj_time});`

The error says "Cannot read property W3C of undefined." Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like an EE bug. $.datepicker is not getting defined for some reason.

Comment: I get that error when I use my own JQuery, and then Safecracker adds its own too. If you do not use your own JQuery and add the datepicker class, it should work, but if you do use your own JQuery, then I dont know how to include the datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's automatically included if you make sure to have the [channel form css](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/index.html#id13) linked:

```
<link href="{path=css/_ee_channel_form_css}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```